# How to animate marker and polyline with react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm using react native maps, redux, redux thunk (and a lot of other cool stuffs)

Any ideas about how to animate my marker and my polyline like this 
[map animation on dribbble](https://dribbble.com/shots/3952560-Travel-Planner-WeeklyUI-Challenge-S02-W03)

I already have the markers and the polyline on my map and I know how to move the map. I want to add 3 effects :

- the pulse effect on the marker,
- draw the polyline from start to arrival with a fancy animation
- make a gradient color on the polyline

Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 2):

It does not appear that you can animate the drawing of a polyline in react native maps, but you can give it a gradient color with the following code (iOS only):

```
import MapView, { Polyline } from 'react-native-maps';

<MapView>
<Polyline
    coordinates={[
        { latitude: 37.8025259, longitude: -122.4351431 },
        { latitude: 37.7896386, longitude: -122.421646 },
        { latitude: 37.7665248, longitude: -122.4161628 },
        { latitude: 37.7734153, longitude: -122.4577787 },
        { latitude: 37.7948605, longitude: -122.4596065 },
        { latitude: 37.8025259, longitude: -122.4351431 }
    ]}
    strokeColor="#000" // fallback for when `strokeColors` is not supported by the map-provider
    strokeColors={[
        '#7F0000',
        '#00000000', // no color, creates a "long" gradient between the previous and next coordinate
        '#B24112',
        '#E5845C',
        '#238C23',
        '#7F0000'
    ]}
    strokeWidth={6}
/>
```

Here is an example of an animated Marker as well:

```
import Mapview, { AnimatedRegion, Marker } from 'react-native-maps';

getInitialState() {

    return {
    coordinate: new AnimatedRegion({
      latitude: LATITUDE,
      longitude: LONGITUDE,
    }),
  };
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  const duration = 500

  if (this.props.coordinate !== nextProps.coordinate) {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      if (this.marker) {
        this.marker._component.animateMarkerToCoordinate(
          nextProps.coordinate,
          duration
        );
      }
    } else {
      this.state.coordinate.timing({
        ...nextProps.coordinate,
        duration
      }).start();
    }
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <MapView initialRegion={...}>
      <MapView.Marker.Animated
        ref={marker => { this.marker = marker }}
        coordinate={this.state.coordinate}
      />
    </MapView>
  );
}
```

More examples can be seen here: https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps